# NinjectValidatorFactory is creating multiple instances of a validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, fluentvalidation, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying to use [Ninject FluentValidation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation) and am having a weird issue -- when I submit a form, the constructor for the validator is being called 32 (!) times.  If I remove the configuration, the constructor is only called once (but of course no injection takes place).  The only thing I can think of is I should be setting up the factory somewhere other than NinjectWebCommon, but I don't see anywhere else I have access to the kernel to do so.

Any ideas why the validator is firing so many times?

In RegisterServices() in NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
NinjectValidatorFactory ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(kernel);
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => provider.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory);
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

In the validation resolver:

```
AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<CleanupSiteValidator>()
            .ForEach(match => Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType));
```

EDIT: I added `InRequestScope()` to the resolver and the constructor for the validator now only fires once, but `CreateInstance()` in `NinjectValidatorFactory.cs` is still firing 32 times.  I suppose this is...better, but should the factory be called this many times?  It seems there is still something wrong.

```
AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<CleanupSiteValidator>()
            .ForEach(match => Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType).InRequestScope());
```

Comment: were you able to find an answer? I'm running into the same issue using StructureMap, I'm curious if this is "working as intended" or not.

Comment: All I've been able to determine is that the number of `CreateInstance` calls is related to the number of properties in the class that is being validated.  If I add five dummy properties, it's called 37 times instead of 32.  I can only assume it's a bug in Fluent.

Comment: Yea I saw that too. For the get method, create instance was called once for each '@Html.TextBoxFor()`. And on Form post it's at least 4 times + (2 or 3 * numberOfProperties)

Comment: This is working as intended within the MVC architecture.